# Logic app to copy files from a blob even if there is no change

Tags: azure, blob, storage, integration, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is triggered when there is a change to the blob, this works fine but what if I want this process to run and overwrite these files is this possible. I seem to lose all dynamic options as soon as I change the bloc modified trigger

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. But if you just want a scheduled job kind of process to pick or put files from/to azure blob storage, you can use blob actions rather than trigger. You can use a 'Recurrence' trigger to start the logic app and use one of the appropriate blob actions to do the required operation. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: I'm actually trying to go from blob to sftp. What I've noticed is that I can just run the app but it will not transfer files from the blob unless there is a change in the blob. I want to copy the files regardless if there was a change or not. Ive tried to replace the when a blob is added trigger with a recurrence or http but I do not get the dynamic options I would get if I added the trigger for when a blob is added.